# I have two BaseAdapter which contain checkboxes, how to check the checkbox of Adapter2 based on the values from the Adapter1

Tags: android, checkbox, android-custom-view, custom-adapter

I am having two BaseAdapter Adapter1 and Adapter2, after checking the checkbox from adapter1 it is saved in the Arraylist and which is passed to Adapter2. I want to check the checkbox of Adapter2 which are selected in the Adapter1. Both Adapter will have the same values.

I have tried but it is giving

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:

as the passed values from the Adapter1.

can anyone please help in this case, please. 
here is the two adapter Adapter1 is

```
public class RouterSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ArrayList<RouterSelectModel> routermodeldata;
ArrayList<RouterSelectModel> rowterselectedmodeldata;
ArrayList<RouterSelectModel>orig;
boolean[] rowtercheckBoxState;
boolean flag;
public RouterSpinnerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RouterSelectModel>routermodeldata, boolean flag){
    this.context=context;
    this.routermodeldata=routermodeldata;
    this.flag=flag;
    rowtercheckBoxState = new boolean[routermodeldata.size()];
    rowterselectedmodeldata=new ArrayList<>();

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return routermodeldata.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return routermodeldata.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder=null;

    if (convertView==null){
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowter_spinner_row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.ch_select_rowter =(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ch_select_rowter);
        viewHolder.t_rowtername=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.t_rowtername);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final RouterSelectModel model=(RouterSelectModel)routermodeldata.get(position);

    viewHolder.t_rowtername.setText(model.getRoutername());
    viewHolder.ch_select_rowter.setChecked(rowtercheckBoxState[position]);

    viewHolder.ch_select_rowter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                    rowtercheckBoxState[position]=true;
                    // selectedManagerHashMap.put(model.getManagername(),model.getManagername());
                   // saveToCustom(model.getDominaname(),sessionManager.getUserID());
                    rowterselectedmodeldata.add(model);
                }else
                {
                    rowtercheckBoxState[position]=false;
                    // selectedManagerHashMap.remove(model.getManagername());
                    //removeFromCustom(model.getDominaname(),sessionManager.getUserID());
                    rowterselectedmodeldata.remove(model);
                }
            }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

            }
        }

    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            final ArrayList<RouterSelectModel> results = new ArrayList<RouterSelectModel>();
            if (orig == null)
                orig = routermodeldata;
            if (charSequence != null) {
                if (orig != null && orig.size() > 0) {
                    for (final RouterSelectModel g : orig) {
                        if (g.getRoutername().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence.toString()))
                            results.add(g);
                    }
                }
                oReturn.values = results;
            }
            return oReturn;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            routermodeldata = (ArrayList<RouterSelectModel>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
 public void selectAllRowter(boolean flag){
if (flag==true){
    for (int i = 0; i <rowtercheckBoxState.length ; i++) {

        rowtercheckBoxState[i]=flag;
        rowterselectedmodeldata.add(routermodeldata.get(i));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}if (flag==false){
    for (int i = 0; i <rowtercheckBoxState.length ; i++) {

        rowtercheckBoxState[i]=flag;
        rowterselectedmodeldata.remove(routermodeldata.get(i));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


 }
 public ArrayList<RouterSelectModel> getseletedItems(){
    return rowterselectedmodeldata;
 }
static class ViewHolder{

    TextView t_rowtername;
    CheckBox ch_select_rowter;
}

 }
```

Adapter2 is

```
     public class Fun2RouterSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ArrayList<Fun2RouterSpinnerModel> fun2routermodeldata;
ArrayList<Fun2RouterSpinnerModel> fun2rowterselectedmodeldata;
ArrayList<Fun2RouterSpinnerModel>orig;
boolean[] fun2rowtercheckBoxState;
boolean flag;
ArrayList<RouterSelectModel> routerlistfrom1;
public Fun2RouterSpinnerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Fun2RouterSpinnerModel>routermodeldata,ArrayList<RouterSelectModel> routerlistfrom1 ,boolean flag){
    this.context=context;
    this.fun2routermodeldata=routermodeldata;
    this.flag=flag;
    fun2rowtercheckBoxState = new boolean[routermodeldata.size()];
    fun2rowterselectedmodeldata=new ArrayList<>();
    this.routerlistfrom1=routerlistfrom1;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fun2routermodeldata.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return fun2routermodeldata.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder=null;

    if (convertView==null){
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fun2_rowter_spinner_row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.ch_select_rowter2 =(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ch_select_rowter2);
        viewHolder.t_rowtername2=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.t_rowtername2);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final Fun2RouterSpinnerModel model=(Fun2RouterSpinnerModel)fun2routermodeldata.get(position);

    viewHolder.t_rowtername2.setText(model.getRouter2name());
    viewHolder.ch_select_rowter2.setChecked(fun2rowtercheckBoxState[position]);




    viewHolder.ch_select_rowter2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                    fun2rowtercheckBoxState[position]=true;
                    // selectedManagerHashMap.put(model.getManagername(),model.getManagername());
                    // saveToCustom(model.getDominaname(),sessionManager.getUserID());
                    fun2rowterselectedmodeldata.add(model);
                }else
                {
                    fun2rowtercheckBoxState[position]=false;
                    // selectedManagerHashMap.remove(model.getManagername());
                    //removeFromCustom(model.getDominaname(),sessionManager.getUserID());
                    fun2rowterselectedmodeldata.remove(model);
                }
            }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

            }
        }

    });
     checkSelected(true,routernamefrom1))
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            final ArrayList<Fun2RouterSpinnerModel> results = new ArrayList<Fun2RouterSpinnerModel>();
            if (orig == null)
                orig = fun2routermodeldata;
            if (charSequence != null) {
                if (orig != null && orig.size() > 0) {
                    for (final Fun2RouterSpinnerModel g : orig) {
                        if (g.getRouter2name().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence.toString()))
                            results.add(g);
                    }
                }
                oReturn.values = results;
            }
            return oReturn;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            fun2routermodeldata = (ArrayList<Fun2RouterSpinnerModel>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
public void fun2selectAllRowter(boolean flag){
    if (flag==true){
        for (int i = 0; i <fun2rowtercheckBoxState.length ; i++) {

            fun2rowtercheckBoxState[i]=flag;
            fun2rowterselectedmodeldata.add(fun2routermodeldata.get(i));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }if (flag==false){
        for (int i = 0; i <fun2rowtercheckBoxState.length ; i++) {

            fun2rowtercheckBoxState[i]=flag;
            fun2rowterselectedmodeldata.remove(fun2routermodeldata.get(i));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


}
public ArrayList<Fun2RouterSpinnerModel> getRoterseletedItems(){
    return fun2rowterselectedmodeldata;
}
public boolean checkSelected(boolean flag,String routernamefrom1){

    for (int i = 0; i <fun2routermodeldata.size() ; i++) {
        if(routernamefrom1.equalsIgnoreCase(fun2routermodeldata.get(i).getRouter2name())){
            fun2rowtercheckBoxState[i]=flag;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
static class ViewHolder{

    TextView t_rowtername2;
    CheckBox ch_select_rowter2;
}
  }
```

Comment: What is the use of this  `rowtercheckBoxState = new boolean[routermodeldata.size()];`. Suppose you have 20 items in your model data then you will 20 false value in your boolean array

Comment: it is in the adapter1 to initialize the number of checkbox present in the view. if we are not doing it then it will null pointer exception of boolean Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got answer by doing some R&D here is the solution.

```
public class DRRouterSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ArrayList<DRRouterSpinnerModel> drroutermodeldata;
ArrayList<DRRouterSpinnerModel> drrowterselectedmodeldata;
ArrayList<DRRouterSpinnerModel>orig;
boolean[] drrowtercheckBoxState;
boolean flag;
ArrayList<TeamRouterSelectModel> routerlistfrom1;
ArrayList<String>datafrom1;

public DRRouterSpinnerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DRRouterSpinnerModel>routermodeldata, ArrayList<TeamRouterSelectModel> routerlistfrom1 , boolean flag, ArrayList<String>datafrom1){
    this.context=context;
    this.drroutermodeldata=routermodeldata;
    this.flag=flag;
    drrowtercheckBoxState = new boolean[routermodeldata.size()];
    drrowterselectedmodeldata=new ArrayList<>();
    this.routerlistfrom1=routerlistfrom1;
    this.datafrom1=datafrom1;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return drroutermodeldata.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return drroutermodeldata.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder=null;

    if (convertView==null){
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fun2_rowter_spinner_row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.ch_select_rowter2 =(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ch_select_rowter2);
        viewHolder.t_rowtername2=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.t_rowtername2);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final DRRouterSpinnerModel model=(DRRouterSpinnerModel)drroutermodeldata.get(position);

    viewHolder.t_rowtername2.setText(model.getRouter2name());
    viewHolder.ch_select_rowter2.setChecked(drrowtercheckBoxState[position]);

    checkSelected(model,position);

    viewHolder.ch_select_rowter2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                    drrowtercheckBoxState[position]=true;
                    // selectedManagerHashMap.put(model.getManagername(),model.getManagername());
                    // saveToCustom(model.getDominaname(),sessionManager.getUserID());
                    drrowterselectedmodeldata.add(model);


                }else
                {
                    drrowtercheckBoxState[position]=false;
                    // selectedManagerHashMap.remove(model.getManagername());
                    //removeFromCustom(model.getDominaname(),sessionManager.getUserID());
                    drrowterselectedmodeldata.remove(model);




                }
            }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

            }
        }

    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            final ArrayList<DRRouterSpinnerModel> results = new ArrayList<DRRouterSpinnerModel>();
            if (orig == null)
                orig = drroutermodeldata;
            if (charSequence != null) {
                if (orig != null && orig.size() > 0) {
                    for (final DRRouterSpinnerModel g : orig) {
                        if (g.getRouter2name().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence.toString()))
                            results.add(g);
                    }
                }
                oReturn.values = results;
            }
            return oReturn;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            drroutermodeldata = (ArrayList<DRRouterSpinnerModel>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
public void fun2selectAllRowter(boolean flag){
    if (flag==true){
        for (int i = 0; i <drrowtercheckBoxState.length ; i++) {

            drrowtercheckBoxState[i]=flag;
            drrowterselectedmodeldata.add(drroutermodeldata.get(i));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }if (flag==false){
        for (int i = 0; i <drrowtercheckBoxState.length ; i++) {

            drrowtercheckBoxState[i]=flag;
            drrowterselectedmodeldata.remove(drroutermodeldata.get(i));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


}
public ArrayList<DRRouterSpinnerModel> getRoterseletedItems(){
   /* HashSet<DRRouterSpinnerModel> hashSet_fun2rowterselectedmodeldata = new HashSet<DRRouterSpinnerModel>();
    hashSet_fun2rowterselectedmodeldata.addAll(fun2rowterselectedmodeldata);
    fun2rowterselectedmodeldata.clear();
    fun2rowterselectedmodeldata.addAll(hashSet_fun2rowterselectedmodeldata);*/

    return drrowterselectedmodeldata;
}
public void checkSelected(DRRouterSpinnerModel model,int position){

    for (int i = 0; i <datafrom1.size() ; i++) {

        if (datafrom1.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(model.getRouter2name())){
            drrowtercheckBoxState[position]=true;
            drrowterselectedmodeldata.add(model);

        }
    }

}

static class ViewHolder{

    TextView t_rowtername2;
    CheckBox ch_select_rowter2;
}
```